# How to refresh the contents of a Materialize CSS Modal?

Tags: javascript, forms, modal-dialog, materialize

**Background:** I'm displaying a list on a website. Each row in the list has an edit button that opens a Materialize CSS modal. Inside the modal is an HTML form that pulls the current values from that specific row in the list, which can be edited with new values.

**Issue:** Once the edits in the modal form are submitted, the modal will retain the values of that specific row, even when selecting a different row. This does not happen when the modal form is not submitted.

**Temporary Solution:** I reload the entire page when the modal is submitted. This way the modal contents are also refreshed, but the user experience suffers since the user needs to always wait for the page to reload.

**Question:** Is there a way to reload or refresh the contents of the modal or the modal form without reloading the whole webpage? Ideally, the modal would refresh and load the correct values for each row after submitting an edit. I am open to other ideas/solutions.

**Code:**

```
 auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
        const editForm = document.querySelector('#edit-form');
      
        editForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
      
          db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('items').doc(editForm.itemID.value).collection('transactions').doc(editForm.transactionID.value).update({
            amount_edit: (parseFloat(editForm.amountEdit.value)*-1).toFixed(2),
            name_edit: editForm.nameEdit.value,
          }).then(() => {
            // close the edit-modal
            const modaledit = document.querySelector('#modal-edit');
            M.Modal.getInstance(modaledit).close();
            editForm.reset();
            location.reload()
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
        })
            } else {
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party. You could reset and then dispatch a focus event for each field.
`editForm.reset()`
`` editForm.querySelectorAll(`[name]`).forEach(i => i.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'))); ``